# regex remove spaces between signs

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I want to remove spaces between leading `>` signs with regex:

```
preg_replace('!^>(?: +)>!m', '>>', $text);
```

that does not work with

```
> > > Hello
```

I want to behave it like this:

```
> >> Hello
> >    > Hello
>>Hello >  >
>>> Hello
> >>     Hello
```

should become

```
>>> Hello
>>> Hello
>> Hello >  >
>>> Hello
>>>     Hello
```

but the second `>` is already used to match with the first two signs.

see: https://regex101.com/r/4uiyWG/1

Comment: Do you have multiline strings in real life? Try [`preg_replace('~(?:\G|^)\h*>\h*~m', '>', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/irTfl4/1).

Comment: Just to clarify: `'> > > Hello > > More text'` should be turned into `'>>> Hello > > More text'`, right? Or `'>>> Hello >> More text'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform replacement on separate strings, use

```
$s = preg_replace('~\G\h*>~', '>', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5nVv8/4)

The `\G` operator matches the start of string or the end of the preceding successful match. `\h*` will match zero or more horizontal whitespace symbols.

If you want to get rid of spaces in between leading `>` on *each line* of the input, use

```
$s = preg_replace('~(?:\G|^)\h*>~m', '>', $s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5nVv8/3)

Here, `(?:\G|^)` alternation is necessary since `\G` (even with the `/m` modifier) won't match the beginning of a line).

Comment: that works quite good, I actually used `(?:\G|^)\h*>` because I want a space after the group of `>`. But I still need to fiddle how to get the space when its not there. I updated the question

Comment: Doesn't it really work? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5nVv8/3).

Comment: I said it works :) but I forgot in my question before 8and updated it now) that I also need to add a space after the `>` if there is none. If there is more than one space its ok. Iam just trying to fiddle it out by my self but would be happy about help

Comment: That is tricky, and I am not sure you can achieve it with one replacement pass. I will think about it.

Comment: yes, I guess its better to do it in a second step, thats ok